# Queue Name not declared, yet it exists in JBoss JMS MQ - How?

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, mq

I have declared only One Queue called MyQueue1 in JBoss JMS MQ - jbossmq-destinations-service.xml , But when i view list of Queues via JBoss JMX Console. I see 5 queues there.

How did other Queues get created?
I have been told that Queues get created automatically when we attempt to write to a non-existent queue - is this possible? I am not able to replicate this behavior on my desktop though.

I am using JBoss 4.0.x
Please advice... Thanks.